# VncSharp, проблема при запуске не из UI потока

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток.

Ковыряюсь с библиотекой VncSharp для работы с RFB протоколом. Использую только клиент VncClient (без использования контрола, зашитого в библиотеке). Проблема в следующем: при запуске клиента из UI потока моего приложения все проходит на ура (изображение присутствует), но при попытке запуска из фонового потока (Task.Run) соединение происходит, но не работает кадровый буфер (не идет отображение изображения).

Нашел в библиотеке данный метод:

```
public void StartUpdates()
    {
        // Start getting updates on background thread.
        worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.GetRfbUpdates));
        // Bug Fix (Grйgoire Pailler) for clipboard and threading
        worker.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        worker.IsBackground = true;
        done = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        worker.Start();
    }
```

который вызывает следующий метод:

```
private void GetRfbUpdates()
    {
        int rectangles;
        int enc;

        // Get the initial destkop from the host
        RequestScreenUpdate(true);

        while (true) {
            if (CheckIfThreadDone())
                break;

            try {
                switch (rfb.ReadServerMessageType()) {
                    case RfbProtocol.FRAMEBUFFER_UPDATE:
                        rectangles = rfb.ReadFramebufferUpdate();

                        if (CheckIfThreadDone())
                            break;

                        // TODO: consider gathering all update rectangles in a batch and *then* posting the event back to the main thread.
                        for (int i = 0; i < rectangles; ++i) {
                            // Get the update rectangle's info
                            Rectangle rectangle;
                            rfb.ReadFramebufferUpdateRectHeader(out rectangle, out enc);

                            // Build a derived EncodedRectangle type and pull-down all the pixel info
                            EncodedRectangle er = factory.Build(rectangle, enc);
                            er.Decode();

                            // Let the UI know that an updated rectangle is available, but check
                            // to see if the user closed things down first.
                            if (!CheckIfThreadDone() && VncUpdate != null) {
                                VncEventArgs e = new VncEventArgs(er);

                                // In order to play nicely with WinForms controls, we do a check here to 
                                // see if it is necessary to synchronize this event with the UI thread.
                                if (VncUpdate.Target is System.Windows.Forms.Control) 
                                {
                                    Control target = VncUpdate.Target as Control;
                                    if (target != null)
                                    {
                                        target.Invoke(VncUpdate, new object[] { this, e });
                                    }
                                }

                                else 
                                {
                                    VncUpdate(this, new VncEventArgs(er));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case RfbProtocol.BELL:
                        Beep(500, 300);  // TODO: are there better values than these?
                        break;
                    case RfbProtocol.SERVER_CUT_TEXT:
                        if (CheckIfThreadDone())
                            break;
                        // TODO: This is invasive, should there be a bool property allowing this message to be ignored?
                        Clipboard.SetDataObject(rfb.ReadServerCutText().Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine), true);
                        OnServerCutText();
                        break;
                    case RfbProtocol.SET_COLOUR_MAP_ENTRIES:
                        rfb.ReadColourMapEntry();
                        break;
                }
            } catch {
                OnConnectionLost();
            }
        }
    }
```

в котором прошу обратить внимание на этот код:

```
// In order to play nicely with WinForms controls, we do a check here to 
// see if it is necessary to synchronize this event with the UI thread.
if (VncUpdate.Target is System.Windows.Forms.Control) 
   {
         Control target = VncUpdate.Target as Control;
         if (target != null)
         {
            target.Invoke(VncUpdate, new object[] { this, e });
         }
    }
    else 
    {
            VncUpdate(this, new VncEventArgs(er));
    }
```

Думаю, проблема в нем. Не совсем понимаю, как его оптимизировать под работу не из UI потока. Также возможно какой-то баг в самой либе.

Я плохо знаком со старой моделью многопоточности (а VncSharp написана под .NET 2.0). Поэтому прошу любой помощи.

P.S. Фреймворк WPF под .NET 4.5.

P.P.S. https://github.com/humphd/VncSharp/tree/master/VncSharp

Answer (score 1):

Пришлось использовать более старую реализацию библиотеки (там где используется Bitmap вместо WriteableBitmap). Проблема ушла.